# Data between two dates using where condition

Tags: sql-server, datetime, stored-procedures

I'am Using a stored procedure to retrieve values between data using Where condition(related to particular Person not the one related to Date).

E.g I have table with cols

```
User Name  User ID  date_used  Book Name
xxxx       UID001   12-03-2012 zzzzz
yyyy       UID002   14-03-2015 ccccc
xxxx       UID001   14-03-2015 rrrrr
```

Desired Out put

```
User Name  User ID  date_used  Book Name
xxxx       UID001   12-03-2012 zzzzz
xxxx       UID001   14-03-2015 rrrrr
```

For this I tried below way, please help me where i'm wrong

```
SELECT     UserID,Issue_Date,Book_Name FROM dbo.Books
where UserID = @userID and Issue_Date >= @From and Issue_Date <= @To
order by Issue_Date Desc
```

@From(datetime) and @to(datetime) are datepickers value(startDate and EndDate)
@userID varchar

When i remove UserID clause I was able to retrive all the books issued for all the users. but when i add a where clause of user id no rows are reflected.

Please advice me on this with other methods to get this done.

Comment: run the query with hard coded values that you are passing to variables and see if it return any rows.

Comment: @Ali tried using that it no Row was returned

Comment: pls add your exact input and datatypes in your table

Comment: Problem sorted then aye :)

Comment: @Aツ Im using Stored procudre, User will select start date and End date from the DatetimePicker(@from and @to). both the datapicker maxdate was set sytem.datetime.now and Custom format of dd-MMM-yyyy.

Comment: @M.Ali  Sorted? would you mind to explain me in details Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Aツ   Datatype - only Date is Datetime and rest are Varchar

Comment: If the hard coded values didnt return any rows it means there is no data for that conditions in where clause.

Comment: @M.Ali  Thats true, but when Hard code was suplied with this format(2015-03-18 16:30:05.877) I was able to  get values

Comment: if its a stored procedure, pls add at first statement a `select @from f, @to t, @userid u` and have a look if the results are what you expect

Comment: The SELECT query looks OK. If you replace @UserID in the query with 'UID001' does it return data?

Comment: @RhysJones Yes Jones, But the value of startdate and enddate should be supplied in this format -   2015-03-18 16:30:05.877. Where as my input are like 18-03-2015 from datetime picker. :(

Comment: @M.Ali thanks got it solved. glad that you lighted me in right way